# JavaScript to allow only numbers, comma, dot, backspace

Tags: javascript, regex

i wrote a javascript function to allow only numbers, comma, dot like this

```
function isNumber(evt) {
              var theEvent = evt || window.event;
              var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
              key = String.fromCharCode(key);
              var regex = /^[0-9.,]+$/;
              if (!regex.test(key)) {
                  theEvent.returnValue = false;
                  if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
              }

}
```

but if i want to remove any number form text box.. backspace is not working. then i changed regex code as  "`var regex = /^[0-9.,BS]+$/;`"

still i am not able to use backspace in textbox.even i cant use left and right keys on textbox is i am doing wrong? can anyone help... thanks. (when I used "BS" in regex instead of backspace its allowing "B","S" Characters in textbox..)

Comment: I cannot test it, but can you try using the regex `/^[0-9.,\b]+$/` instead?

Comment: for backspace its working, thanks. but still I can’t move curser left or right in text box..

Comment: If you are using `jquery`, try [alphanumeric](http://www.shiguenori.com/material/alphanumeric/index.html) plugin

Comment: Don't annoy users, you only care what the value is when it's sent to the server. Sniffing keystrokes doesn't check input that is entered via other means. Instead, provide on–screen hints for format, validate input before sending and let users figure it out.

Comment: @vishnureddy Ouch, you're also validating that? I don't think you should be using regex to do all this. I'm not that all familiar with JQuery, but what RobG said makes sense.

Comment: I thought if user can move the cursor he can edit the number instead of deleting till that part using backspace... ok i will try... Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code:

```
function isNumber(evt) {
          var theEvent = evt || window.event;
          var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
          key = String.fromCharCode(key);
          if (key.length == 0) return;
          var regex = /^[0-9.,\b]+$/;
          if (!regex.test(key)) {
              theEvent.returnValue = false;
              if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
          }
}
```

Comment: this doesn´t allow comma or dot

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, I modified it and worked for me to allow and comma, dot and digits only.

```
function isNumber(evt) {
   var theEvent = evt || window.event;
   var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;            
   var keyCode = key;
   key = String.fromCharCode(key);          
   if (key.length == 0) return;
   var regex = /^[0-9.,\b]+$/;            
   if(keyCode == 188 || keyCode == 190){
      return;
   }else{
      if (!regex.test(key)) {
         theEvent.returnValue = false;                
         if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
      }
    }    
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have combined a couple of scripts together. For me, I only wanted numbers and one comma.

```
    $("#TBDepositAmount").keyup(function () {//if a full stop gets through, on keyup, it is changed to a comma
        var val = $(this).val();
        var str = val.replace('.', ',');
        $(this).val(str);
    });

    $("#TBDepositAmount").keydown("keypress keydown blur", function (event) {            

        var key = event.charCode || event.keyCode || 0;
        if ((key == 110 || key == 190) && $(this).val().split(",").length == 1) { //checks whether input is a full stop and lets only 1 through
            return;
        }
        else
            return ( // check if it is a number, only allows numbers through
                key == 8 ||
                key == 9 ||
                key == 13 ||
                key == 46 ||
                (key >= 35 && key <= 40) ||
                (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
                (key >= 96 && key <= 105));                           
    });
```

My input is as follows:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.deposits.depositAmount, new { @class = "form-control ", autocomplete = "off", id = "TBDepositAmount" })
```