# java script to allow valid numbers with comma and dot

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I test valid numbers in the format of?

```
Accepted:-
    100,000
    100,000.00
    100,000.0000
    10,000,000.00
    0.00
    10000.000
Not Accept:-
    ,100,00,.
    ,.100.00
    100.00,00
    100..,,
```

( only allow single dot(decimal point) and multiple commas, but the number should not start or end with comma or dot, there should not be any improper use of comma and dots as shown above) I tried the following java script for it but it couldn’t solve my issue. Can anyone update my function…

```
 function isNumber(evt) {
         var theEvent = evt || window.event;
         var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
         key = String.fromCharCode(key);
         if (key.length == 0) return;
         var regex = /^(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d+)?$/;
         //var regex = /^[0-9.,]+$/;
         if (!regex.test(key)) {
             theEvent.returnValue = false;
             if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
         }
     }
```

Comment: You haven't really tried, have you? `/^(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d+)?$/`

Comment: its not working. with this code even i am not able to type comma and dot. can you update your code. thanks..

Comment: Blah, missed a closing parens. Change `+)(?:` to `+))(?:`

Comment: Vishnu, by marking one answer as correct (or most helpful), you help other visitors to find solutions, and you reward answers. If the problem is not solved, ask more. If you found a different solution, you can answer your own question. Or, if your're asking the same question multiple times, you can link to the on which gets the correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21374605/java-script-to-allow-only-numbers-comma-dot-back-space

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
var numRegex = /^(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*|0)(?:\.\d+)?$/;

numRegex.test("1,000,000");
numRegex.test("100,000");
numRegex.test("100,000.00");
```

Comment: the number you are entering must be valid. means **100,00.00** is not a valid format number at all. This should be **10,000.00**

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
^(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+|)$
```

Expl.: Match one to three digits. Then allow any number of groups with a comma followed by three digits. If no match on previous, try any number of digits (more than one). Then allow optional decimals. Change to

```
 ^(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)\.\d+$
```

if decimals are mandatory.

Check out [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/jA4xX8)

Regards

Comment: Just noticed you seem to allow groups with other than three digits. Is that correct? In that case change values inside the braces accordingly.

Comment: its not working. if i used above code even i can't select comma and dot also. can you update your code.

Comment: I missed that you allow number w/o commas. Edited answer. Note - you can't validate using this WHILE typing. Only "on exit".

Comment: how do I make that the first number is not 0 or negative number ?

Comment: @Markov I assume you mean that it doesn't start with more that one digit whereof the first is a `0`. You could insert a negative look-ahead in the beginning of the regex: `(?!0\d)` making it `^(?!0\d)(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+|)$`. It assures it doesn't start with a zero followed by another digit. Won't hinder zero followed by a comma or *dot* though. [Here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/jA4xX8/5).

Comment: @SamWhan I ended up doing this ^((?=[^0]))(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+|)$ , 
so the look ahead needs to make sure the first one isnt 0 ((?=[^0])), I laso need to modify to match my case so Here is the regix I come up with https://regex101.com/r/WivNBH/1

Answer (score 1):

Check this :  `^((?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+)(?:\.\d+)?)$`

**[DEMO and Explanation](http://regex101.com/r/rJ0hW0)**

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the problem is not (only?) with the regex, but rather with the event handler: It's accepting a single character, creating a `String` from this single character, and then matching that against the regex.

```
var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
key = String.fromCharCode(key);
```

will never give you a string. If you must use a character-grabbing event, you'll have to use a global variable to accumulate the string over several keystrokes.

The other alternative is to use a textfield and validate the field content when the cursor leaves the field.

If you need assistance with that, please add information which event is handled by `isNumber` and what interaction you want to achieve (keystroke handling or text field or whatever else).

EDIT:

You'll have to find out from the keystroke event which field the user is in. Get the text value of that field, and match the regex against the field value, not against the single keystroke.

The tricky thing is the first one, I figure. Either you create an event handler only for the text field you need to validate, or (if there's several fields to validate) you create the handler for a DOM element containing all these fields, and look at `event.target` (and hopefully the browsers you target are compliant enough to support this), which gives you the DOM element the event was triggered.

Comment: i want to test the text box value when cursor leaves the text box, if possible while typing itself...

Comment: So you want to turn the text field red as long as no number is entered (or, equivalently, turn on a "submit" button only when a legal number is entered)? See my updated answer for a recipe to do that.